# String formatting. Swift / iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I ran into such a problem: from the server I receive such a figure in the string format "20760.326586753041" (example), but I want to change it so that the user's screen has such a figure 20,761.93.
How can I format it?

Tried to do like this:

```
    func setup(coin: Coin) {
        self.nameCoin.text = coin.name
        self.symbolCoin.text = coin.symbol
        self.priceCoin.text = String(format: "%.2f", coin.priceUsd)
        
    }
```

Show 0.0 on screen

Comment: Hint: NumberFormatter.

Comment: You can use `NumberFormatter`

Comment: `priceCoin.text = coin.priceUsd.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(2)))
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `NumberFormatter`

```
import Foundation

let coinFormatter : NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-US")
    return formatter
}()


let stringFromServer = "20760.326586753041"
if let value = coinFormatter.number(from: stringFromServer),
   let reformattedString = coinFormatter.string(for: value) {
    print(reformattedString)
}
```

I create a number formatter called `coinFormatter` that format numbers into decimals that have at most 2 decimal places.  The code below that shows how you might use such a number formatter to convert the string from the server to a number, then the number back to a string with the expected format.

It also looks like you might be trying to format the number as a currency value.  There are mechanisms in `NumberFormatter` for properly formatting currency values that you should look into as well.

P.S.  As you will see in the comments below, `NumberFormatter` takes into account many complexities like the Locale and common radix marks used, how you want negative numbers represented, or whether the currency symbol should be written before or after the number when representing money.  Please take the time to learn more about `NumberFormatter` and the power it offers you.

Comment: You should set the locale for the NumberFormatter to en_US_POSIX so the code works no matter what the users locale is

Comment: I added a locale.

Comment: In the original code, I used `Double(stringFromServer)` instead of using the number formatter I created.  I thought it would be nice to show that the `NumberFormatter` is appropriate for both conversion both ways.  My intent was more to show that the number formatter was the correct topic to investigate, and that it could solve the specific problem presented, rather than to demonstrate all the complexities of number formatting.  I've added a short note about those complexities.